# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud' in PyCharm Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, gcloud

I'm trying to get a BigQuery response based on an SQL query, but the following import fails in the PyCharm Jupyter notebook:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

I'm able run the query successfully on the foll:

- VsCode jupyter notebook
- PyCharm python file

But the import fails only in the PyCharm Jupyter notebook (even if I call the google cloud functions in a python file and import it here in the notebook):

Given that it runs in a python file, I'm certain that I've imported the required libraries properly, and there are no circular dependencies anywhere.

I've also confirmed that the `python` being used by the notebook and my terminal where I installed the packages is the same.

Running `!pip freeze` in the notebook gives me:

```
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-bigquery==3.17.2
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.24.0
google-cloud-core==2.4.1
google-cloud-storage==2.14.0
```

Comment: You'll have a better experience in modern Jupyter using `%pip` and no longer an exclamation point in conjunction with `pip`. While may not help solve the issue you are having, it will be better in the long run, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic commands added in 2019 to insure things run in the environment where the kernel is running.

Comment: Thank you, @Wayne. I did try that, and restarted my IDE, after which I commented those installs in the notebook, and now it works like a "charm". Before doing this, the website you shared led me to find that the notebook was not using the venv of the project. Not sure how this exactly got solved, but you have saved me much time.

Comment: Glad you added that you had to restart things. I forgot to add that depending on how complex the install is, the more things you have to restart. Usually it is at least the kernel in Jupyter, however, it can be much more for complex installs like ipywidgets.